# Applications not showing in Unity Dash

Tags: 12.04, unity-2d

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on an IBM ThnkPad T42.  I just installed Gnome and Cinnamon but I am still using Unity.  The only problem is that in dash when I search for any application they don't appear.  I don't see recent applications either.  I fixed it by running `unity --reset` but the next time I turned on my computer it was broken again

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reinstall `unity-lens-applications` and `unity-lens-files` logged out and back in and it should work.

Comment: Working - Affirmative!

Comment: It was working. But it is not working after the reinstall.

Comment: Worked for me under 14.04 LTS... Thanks!

Comment: It worked on Ubuntu 16.04 as well.

Comment: This is strange issue, that it still goes on in 16.04 from 12.04...

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

1. Switch to tty1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and login as myself.
2. `rm -rf ~/.compiz` (in order to recursively delete session logs... there might also be `~/.compiz-1` and so on, delete them all!)
3. `sudo service lightdm restart`
4. login using the standard greeter again.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/943083/comments/14

Comment: Still working on 15.10

Answer (score 1):

The Unity Dash shows applications which have `.desktop` shortcuts in `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`. So ensure that the application has a `.desktop` shortcut in at least one of these two folders.

Comment: I have .desktop files in those locations but no applications show up until i run <code> unity -- reset </code>

Comment: could reinstalling unity also help

Comment: I tried putting <code> unity -- reset </code> into my start up but that didn't work because when unity resets the desktop environment break

Answer (score 1):

Enter Ubuntu software center, search for unity > "More Info" and if you scroll down, there are "Optional addons". Check unity lens files and applications then apply.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Go to `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/` and open in gedit the mpv.desktop file (if it is there, if not, probably try to create one).

If there is a line

```
NoDisplay=true
```

change it to

```
NoDisplay=false
```

Answer (score -2):

This command will restore the configuration of dash:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -A
```

It should be working.

Comment: Can you please edit and improve your answer. What exactly does the given command do and does it improve/solve the OP's issue!

Comment: this for unity dash for not showing installed application, that command will restore the configuration of dash to be to able see again all application installed. look at this my previews problem http://imgur.com/scnOTpv

Comment: after try using that command, this it now http://imgur.com/scnOTpv

Comment: -1 This command reconfigures **ALL** packages, not just Unity/Dash.