# Dash (from Unity) does not showing Applications

Tags: unity

I have a weird issue with Unity, it just stopped showing applications in the unity dash search menu.
I can't launch application unless I run them from the terminal.

I have tried to force unity re-installation with no success, and I could not find any other information regarding to this issue. Prior to full re-installation (I prefer not to, since my disk is encrypted) I am seeking for help. (I am a developer and would love to help with more information as needed).

[image: An image]

An image to applications is shown like this, when looking at Ubuntu dash search feature.

Comment: I think you're talking about the Ubuntu **dash** search engine. You can upload a picture and leave only a _link_ to it.

Comment: ok - Thanks, this is the link to the image [link](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-TOp9eaPu1QA/UhHM9skH8sI/AAAAAAAABu4/JCGcaG6g-Oo/w1056-h659-no/noapps.png)

Comment: Searching for applications missing in dash, I got to [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225519/applications-not-showing-in-unity-dash) I re installed unity-lens-applications and unity-lens-files and log out, but nothing had changed, any idea??

Comment: trying this as well `mv ~/.local/share/zeitgeist ~/.local/share/zeitgeist.bak`

Comment: That did not help either. is there a way to re-install the whole unity package?

Comment: Any one??? Who is there to help???

Comment: I need to say, I'm very disppointed with ubuntu 13.10. it is a bit crash. I have the same problem, it happen right after I had unistall a VPN program called "Safejumper", I just remove the folde in my /home/<user>/SafeJumper and /home/<user>/.SafeJumper The ubuntu stop showing my application in the Dash Search. I'm pretty sure in my case was SafeJumper responsible for the trouble.

Comment: I will move back to opensuse, ubuntu disappointed me in so many ways. To many "frufru"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applications don't appear in the Dash (14.04)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/501880/applications-dont-appear-in-the-dash-14-04)

Answer (score 33):

Try to remove and re-install **unity-lens-applications**

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-applications    
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications
```

**Edit**: Log off & login. If doesn't work restart your system (see comments)

Comment: 10x but it did not helped :-(
Still can not see applications in dash!

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: @rpadovani Just to say! Your tip work for me. But you need to restart your system after apply. Thanks for save my day! ;)

Comment: I had this same problem. Your solution worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Worked for me, Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Answer (score 16):

Delete the .cache directory from home folder, logout and login again. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, But I already reinstalled the system.

Comment: In case you encounter the same issue again this should help you.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: deleting ~/.cache/unity* worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I finally found out why the installed Applications were not showing up. Check for Filters options while searching and select the Applications button.

Mine was not selected so it was listing due to filters applied.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This command will restart zeitgeist daemon which sometimes fails to start and unity dash does not showing applications

```
sudo zeitgeist-daemon --replace
```

Comment: @damadam do you understand now?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem. To solve it i deleted the recent files I had downloaded that were not on the software centre (i.e livewallpaper and the files related), used 'sudo apt-get autoremove' and then 'sudo reboot'.

Answer (score -1):

Had this problem after unticking in Unity Tweak Tool > Web Apps > Preauthorized domains > Amazon

Reverted to default and got search working again