# Applications not visible in launcher

Tags: launcher, unity-dash

I have installed ubuntu 14.10. the problem is the applications wont show in ubuntu dash(clicking on launcher icon and search for application) i have installed google chrome and virtual box ( downloaded both from their websites NOT through ubuntu software center) these applications dont show up in the dash. but if i restart the PC then those applications show up properly. What to do for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, with some fixes. Happens to me from time to time.
Bug:
[Dash (from Unity) does not showing Applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334151/unity-not-showing-applications)

Fix: Work your way through the suggestions listed here.
[Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

Comment: the problem i am facing is that ONLY THE APPLICATIONS WHICH ARE INSTALLED WITHOUT DOWNLOADING THROUGH UBUNTU SOFTWARE CENTER( I HAVE DOWNLOADED .deb FILE FOR CHROME AND VIRTUAL BOX FROM GOOGLE AND ORACLE VIRTUAL BOX WEBSITES AFTER DOWNLOADING I JUST CLICKED ON THEM THEN UBUNTU SOFTWARE CENTER OPENED AND INSTALLED THOSE APPLICATIONS.AFTER FINISHING INSTALLATION I CLICKED ON THE UNITY DASH AND SEARCHED FOR CHROME AND VIRTUAL BOX BUT THEY DIDNT SHOW UP IN SEARCH RESULT AND ALL OTHER APPLICATIONS ARE SHOWING IN SEARCH RESULT. I RESTART MY PC AND THESE APPS SHOW UP NORMALLY

Comment: No need to yell. So it sounds like from your comment, that the problem is that some programs, which you install from downloaded .deb files, don't show up in the dash untill you restart your computer. Is that right?

Comment: dude i am not yelling. yes thats right the downloaded .deb files dont show up in the dash until i restart the PC. any solution for this?