# Launch GIMP from the launcher

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, launcher, gimp

I have the default installation of GIMP which comes with Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS (2.8.22).

I'm a fan of launching programmes by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> then typing the name:
[image: Launching Firefox from the launcher]

But I've tried every combination of names for starting GIMP and the application is never found. I've tried `gimp`, `GIMP`, `GNU`, `image`.

Why does GIMP not show in the launcher?

Comment: Does `ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i gimp` outputs anything ?

Comment: You may need to restart (or logout / login again), or, if it still does't show, try deleting cache as per here: [Dash (from Unity) does not showing Applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334151/dash-from-unity-does-not-showing-applications).

Comment: @N.Cornet No, that grep doesn't find anything.

Comment: Does `gimp` start from the command line? How did you install it? (`gimp` is not part of the default installation of Ubuntu.) In my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I have `gimp version 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1`, which is another version than yours.

Comment: (2.8.22) is not the "default installation of GIMP " in 16.04 from a debian package. You most likely installed the snap version of gimp which could be behind not showing in the Dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If as it appears you installed the snap version of gimp in 16.04 you won't find it in the Dash. This should allow it to appear

`sudo apt install snapd-xdg-open`
Then try a log out/in, (may work) or a restart will definitely work

Also note that the snap version of gimp installed from the software manager will be confined. If you need it to open files from other partitions then remove the snap & re-install using the `--classic` option. Ex.

`sudo snap remove gimp`

`sudo snap install gimp --classic`

Note that there is little support for bugs with snaps, no launchpad bug reporting, ect. More like what you get installing apps from play stores like google's and apple's.

Comment: I've never heard of snap, but I must've installed GIMP from the Ubuntu Software Centre, which shows two versions, 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1, and the 2.8.22 I had installed. Very confusing! Uninstalled the 2.8.22 and installed 2.8.16. Problem solved! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to create a `.desktop` file for GIMP**

Simply open a terminal and type

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gimp.desktop
```

and paste this in the editor

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=GNU Image Manipulation Program
GenericName=Image Editor
Comment=Create images and edit photographs
Exec=/snap/bin/gimp
Icon=gimp
Terminal=false
Categories=Graphics;2DGraphics;RasterGraphics;GTK;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=GIMP
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=General
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.8.20
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-OtherBinaries=gimp-2.8
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=image/bmp;image/g3fax;image/gif;image/x-fits;image/x-pcx;image/x-portable-anymap;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/x-portable-graymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/x-psd;image/x-sgi;image/x-tga;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-xwindowdump;image/x-xcf;image/x-compressed-xcf;image/x-gimp-gbr;image/x-gimp-pat;image/x-gimp-gih;image/tiff;image/jpeg;image/x-psp;application/postscript;image/png;image/x-icon;image/x-xpixmap;image/svg+xml;application/pdf;image/x-wmf;image/x-xcursor;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gimp20
```

Where `/snap/bin/gimp` after `Exec=` is the command that the 'icon' will run. In this case, according to a command, we assume that you installed the snap version of GIMP, if that is not the case, replace this line by

```
Exec=gimp-2.8
```

Save the file and exit the editor.

You'll need to log out and log back in.

Comment: `sudo` alone shouldn't be used with GUI programs, since it can mess with the ownership of files in your home directory (by making them owned by `root`). Instead, `sudo -H` should be used.

Comment: If in fact he installed the snap version of gimp you'd need to adjust some parts of your .desktop file. I'd say it's 90+% likely that is what the op has.

Comment: The Exec= line would need to be /snap/bin/gimp The TryExec the same or removed. Best place to save file would be ~/.local/share/applications & not as root.

Comment: I updated my answer, but as you explain in your answer, if it was installed with snap, my answer isn't appropriated...