# Unable to find any of my applications in Dash?

Tags: unity-dash

I am new in Ubuntu.

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and I try to access installed application but dash will not show me any. I can see them installed in Software Center but when I search through Dash I get nothing under any filter.

Secondary question: how do I customize Dash so it does not show me all of songs when I search for an application?

Comment: What applications? Refer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225519/applications-not-showing-in-unity-dash), and try turning off the online search results in the Privacy settings.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the installed applications in this folder

```
/usr/share/applications
```

All the installed applications will be shown here.

And regarding dash..
Open dash and click "filter results" on the right side.
Choose "Applications" while searching for applications.

Comment: Great but how do I make this an easy access folder and why they are not shown in Dash?

Comment: You can create a folder in desktop and go to the applications folder as told above and select the apps which u want to use frequently and copy them and paste it in the new folder created in the desktop.

And pls vote up or accept the answer if you got what you want.

Comment: They are not shown in Dash may be because you didn't select the category "Applications" in the filter results column of Dash.

Comment: Thank you Assassin, but I do select the category of Application and search for all and .... I think it is a bug! In any case the workaround should do for now.

Comment: Can you post the contents of any one application's .desktop file which is not shown in dash? Go to terminal and go to the location /usr/share/applications and select any application and open it with gedit and post the contents of that file.