# How to fix all applications missing in Ubuntu's dash?

Tags: 16.04, unity-dash

having an issue with the dashboard where applications don't show app in the applications lense or when searched. Tried everything in these topics:

[Applications not showing in Unity Dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225519/applications-not-showing-in-unity-dash)

[Dash (from Unity) does not showing Applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334151/dash-from-unity-does-not-showing-applications)

But nothing has worked so far. Would really wat to avoid reinstalling everything since i use Vivaldi and there is no where to export my stuff from it. Using 16.04

Edit: All apps aren't being displayed, only show files and web results. Checked the filters: applications is enabled

Edit 2: after a reboot got a crash report, might be related since the culprit of the crash was unity-lens-loader. Will try to purge and see what happens.
Could not purge it, unity-lens-loader is not a package, it's a executable created by libunity9, should I purge and reinstall it?

Comment: All apps, only show files and web results. Checked the filters, applications is enabled

Comment: Sorry but if all apps are missing, I can't help.

Comment: @DiogoGomes no problem, just hope to find someone here that can help or if they know of ways to fully export everything from Vivaldi so that i can just reinstall the system or if they know of other ways to list all installed apps that is as elegant as dash, i'll take it

Comment: The other questions you linked have many different solutions. Could you please tell us what exactly you have tried already? And could you add a screenshot of what you see please?

Comment: @wjandrea tried reinstalling unity-lens-applications and lens-files, tried deleting .compiz in my home folder, tried adding the mpv.desktop file in applications folder in usr/share and .local/share, tried dpkg-reconfigure, tried to delete the zeitgeist file and tried to delete the .cache folder

Comment: after a reboot took a look at a system crash report, this might be related to the issue. Says that unity-scope-loader is crashing, will try to purge it and reinstall

Comment: @BressanFranco Please add that info to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been fixed; the apps are showing up again. I am not sure what fixed it, but here are all the things I did before the next reboot:

I renamed `unity-scope-loader` to `unity-scope-loader.bak` in `/usr/bin`. I
tried to reinstall `libunity9` though it always gave me an error that it couldn't overwrite `unity-scope-loader`. Finally, I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libunity9`.

Comment: This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I've fixed it by running `sudo apt install 'gnome-shell-extension-*'` then logging out and logging back in. I don't know which extension it was that was missing exactly, but the brute force method fixed the issue.

Comment: That's ... a lot of extensions to install. By default, `appindicator`, `desktop-icons`, `prefs`, and `ubuntu-dock` are installed and running 

Answer (score 0):

#### On 18.04, I used the dconf tool application and I navigated to the dconf setting: **com > canonical > unity > lenses**

From here, I changed the value for:

**always-search** to

```
['applications.scope']
```

and

**home-lens-default-view** to

```
['applications.scope', 'info.scope', 'info-calculator.scope']
```

---

#### Also, I navigated to the dconf setting: **com > canonical > unity > dash**

and I changed the value for **scopes** to

```
['applications.scope', 'home.scope', 'files.scope', 'photos.scope', 'video.scope', 'music.scope', 'social.scope']
```

As you can see, the applications scope is now the first one on the list. This step may not be necessary (it appears to only change the order of which the)

Answer (score -1):

Go to System Settings -> Security & Privacy. At Files & Applications tab click "Clear usage data". In the dialog select "From all time".

Comment: sorry nothing :(
tried to reboot and just looked the detail of a system crash, might be related, says that unity-scope-loader has crashed